# Continuously getting same error while creating react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

[image]

Getting above error again and again Because of this error, In package.json no scripts are getting added
Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.1.2",
    "postinstall-js": "^0.7.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the node version?

Comment: I dont think if its an error. Its just an warning. Try doing `npm i --verbose` to get detailed logs to npm install,